# Graph searching with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to search some query in form `People who live in foo and like bar` with facebook graph api using Graph explorer tool.

how i can build the same query?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to do a GET on the person's Facebook ID, for example for my page:

```
Dim cli As New FacebookClient(accessToken) 'Make sure Facebook API is installed with the Package Manager

Dim location = cli.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/10152364187187493?fields=location")
specific_location = location("name")
```

I'm not really sure how to find out what someone's likes are, but you can test things out using the Graph API Explorer if you haven't already done so.